# Continued addition and under rooting of 12

Tags: exponentiation, square-numbers

$\sqrt{(12 + \sqrt{12......})}$ **and so on**....
How do I find its answer? This is a question in our class VII mats book.
**P.S. - Answer is 4**

Comment: Assuming the limit exists, call it $x$. Squaring it we find $$x^2=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}^2=12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\cdots}}=12+x$$ Now you can solve for $x $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{(12 + \sqrt{12......})}=x$

$$x^2=12+\sqrt{(12 + \sqrt{12......})}=12+x$$

$$x^2-x-12=0$$

$$(x-4)(x+3)=0$$

$$x=4 \text{ or } x=-3 \text{ (rejected as $x>0$)}$$

Comment: Better if you also show the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be $4$. Let $x=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\ldots}}$.  Then $x$ satifies the equation
$x^2-12=x$ or $x^2-x-12=0$.  The only solutions are $4$ and $-3$.  Since $x$ is positive it must be $4$.

Comment: Oops.. Sorry my bad .. its 4.. editing it now.